# Using Ansible to Configure Multiple Drives with LVM

Tags: ansible, lvm

In full disclaimer I am a bit of a neophyte with Ansible and I might be biting off more than I can chew, but I have a need to be able to configure IO servers. Think of them as the front-end servers for Gluster, or Lustre OSS servers, etc... Each of these servers has 10 drives. I can configure a single drive using

```
  - name: VGCreate vg_gluster1
    lvg: vg={{ "vg_gluster1" }} pvs={{ "/dev/sdb" }} state=present
  - name: LVCreate vg_gluster1
    lvol: vg={{ "vg_gluster1" }} lv={{ "brick1" }} size={{ "1000m" }}
  - name: Create Filesystem vg_gluster1
    filesystem: fstype={{ "xfs" }} dev={{ "/dev/vg_gluster1/brick1" }}
  - name: Create Mount Points vg_gluster1
    file: path={{ "/brick1" }} state=directory mode=0777 recurse=yes
  - name: Mount Filesystem vg_gluster1
    mount: name={{ "/brick1" }} src={{ "/dev/vg_gluster1/brick1" }} state=mounted fstype=xfs
```

I would like to understand how to loop over all 10 drives, keeping in mind that vg_gluster1 is associated with /dev/sdb, vg_gluster2 with sdc, etc... Does anyone have any insight to help out?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Define drives list:

```
mydrives:
  - /dev/sdb
  - /dev/sdc
```

Make a task file `lvm.yml`:

```
- name: VGCreate vg_gluster1
  lvg: vg={{ "vg_gluster"+myindex }} pvs={{ mydrive }} state=present
- name: LVCreate vg_gluster1
  lvol: vg={{ "vg_gluster"+myindex }} lv={{ "brick"+myindex }} size={{ "1000m" }}
... etc ...
```

Then make looped include:

```
- include: lvm.yml
  vars:
    myindex: "{{ item.0 }}"
    mydrive: "{{ item.1 }}"
  with_indexed_items: "{{ mydrives }}"
```

This will include `lvm.yml` for each drive from `mydrives` list.

If you want different name for every volume (not `vg_gluster<index>`), you can define `mydrives` list like this:

```
mydrives:
  - vg: vg_name
    dev: /dev/sdb
    size: 1000m
  - vg: vg_other
    dev: /dev/sdc
    size: 500m
```

And modify `lvm.yml` accordingly.